# Register a Local BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

Is there anyway to register a BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml and receives broadcast that is send by a LocalBroadcastManager?

Currently I must call

```
registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)
```

to register a Receiver, declare in AndroidManifest.xml won't work. But this means I must know exactly the receiver's package name and class name, not just the intent filter. Is it possible to declare the receiver in the manifest file?

following is my current code.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<receiver 
    android:name="com.example.test.MessageReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.m2x.test.intent.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

MainActivity.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.m2x.test.intent.MESSAGE_RECEIVED");

LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext.get());
manager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

MessageReceiver.java

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.m2x.test.intent.MESSAGE_RECEIVED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "user message received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes its possible to declare it in manifest please share your manifest file to find issue

Comment: Yes I know normal broadcast receiver can be declared in xml. But I want to use LocalBroadcastManager because of security problem. I declared the receiver in the xml but it seem does't work...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, you can't.

The local `BroadcastReceiver` isn't a real `BroadcastReceiver`, basically its a list of `callbacks` functions.
You can check the source code of [LocalBroadcastManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-support-lib-19.1.0/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java).