# Android - How to register a LocalBroadcastManager receiver in a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `NetworkReceiver` class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`. Its `onReceive()` method is called when there is a connectivity change and, if there is a connection, my `SyncIntentService` is called which exchanges data with the server.

When completed, `SyncIntentService` sends a local broadcast via `LocalBroadcastManager`, but I am not sure of the best way to set up my `NetworkReceiver` class to listen for these local broadcasts.

The issue is that there does not seem to be a `Context` object available in `NetworkReceiver` to pass to `LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);`.

Actually, there is the `Context` object that is passed in to `NetworkReceiver`'s `onReceive()` method, but I'm not sure if it would the best practice to register a `LocalBroadcastManager` receiver there.

Is there a better way?

NB - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23366125/1617737) explains why you can't register a `LocalBroadcastManager` receiver in the manifest, so that obviously isn't an option.

Comment: Since NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver, you probably have a override onReceive method. The context is passed there, is not it?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I had already stated that in my question. Was asking if there was a better way.